# Was Cliff Robertson a Real Ventriloquist?

Tags: the-twilight-zone

In the *Twilight Zone* episode *The Dummy*, there's a scene where "Jerry and Willie" (Robertson's character and the titular ventriloquist dummy) are performing and it looks like the actor's lips move a bit while he's doing the voice of the dummy.

What surprised me was that the act was very good! So good in fact I thought it was a voice over except for a couple of phrases where I could see lip movement.

I've searched around a bit online, but due to the popularity of the episode most results are synopses.

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if Robertson's script called for him to make subtle movement of the lips from time to time, while the actual dummy was voiced over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

George Murdock is credited for Willie, as seen on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734636/?ref_=ttep_ep33)